# Basic attempt at using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js

I tried to follow an example on the web for creating a NodeJS server and router, but have ran into problems. What follows is primarily the example with a bit of other code.

Index.js

```
var server = require("./server");
var router = require("./router");
server.start(router.route);'
```

Router.js

```
var fs = require("fs");

function route(filename) {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
        console.log('Error: ' + err);
        return;
        }
        console.log("About to route a request for " + filename);
        data = JSON.parse(data);

    })
} 
exports.route = route;
```

Server.js

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");


function start(route) {

    function onRequest(request, response) {
         var filename = request.url.substr(1);
          // call for specific json file here
        if (filename == "favicon.ico") {
            response.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
            response.end();
            console.log('favicon requested');
            return;
        }
        else {
            filename += ".json";            
            console.log("Request for " + filename + " received.");  

            response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" });
            response.write("" + route(filename),0,4);
            response.end();
        }
    }    

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8124);
}    

exports.start = start;
console.log('Server running at http://127.0.0.1:8124/');
```

The question I have is, among others, how does the route command work?
What I get when I browse to the server is 'undefined'. How do I get the actual json from the Router?

I tried: var result = route(filename); but that failed badly.

In essence, how to get the data from the router and write it to the response. If you haven't guessed, javascript and NodeJS is rather new to me.

Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your route function has an async method, `fs.readFile`. You'll need to pass in a callback to the route function, so that it can return the data properly. Otherwise, `route` will return immediately with no data (since it's async) regardless if you have a return statement inside `readFile`.

router.js

```
function route(filename, callback) {
    fs.readFile(filename, 'utf8', function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
            console.log('Error: ' + err);
            return;
        }
        console.log("About to route a request for " + filename);
        data = JSON.parse(data);
        callback(data); // Call this function after the data is grabbed.
    })
}
```

server.js portion:

```
response.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*" });
route(filename, function (data) {
    response.write("" + JSON.stringify(data),0,4);
    response.end();
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That is a massive improvement. Not to trouble you to much, but the only thing is I am getting a response of the actual data type [object Object] instead of the actual information. How would I fix this?

Comment: @sum1nil, you would just need to call `JSON.stringify`, or you could call whatever properties that data would contain, such as `data.ID`. I've updated the server.js part.